# Why does the FrontEnd lose matching of parentheses when we insert quotations?

Tags: bugs, front-end, version-10, parsing

**Bug introduced in V10.0 and resolved in V11.3**

(These are guesses.  It is likely to have been resolved in an earlier version V11.X, but V11.3 is what I have access to.)

---

I am running Mathematica 10.0.1 on a four-year old iMac running OS 10.6.8. The following irritating behavior occurs regularly: I have a list with parentheses, and later on I need to add something to an earlier part of the list that involves quotation marks. As soon as I include the quotation marks, the matching between the parentheses gets lost, and I need to go in by hand to fix the parentheses matching. See the gif below for an example.

This also happens in version 10.0.2.0 on a 2014 MacBook Air running OS 10.10.4. I have verified that this does *not* happen in Mathematica 8 on the four-year old iMac.

Is this problem reproducible in general? How do we fix it? Is it already fixed in a later version? If so, is there a work-around without upgrading? Should this be reported as a bug to WRI?

[image]

Comment: Same for me: MMA v10.2, OSX 10.9.5

Comment: Yes, I see the same behavior in 10.2 on Win7-64. Interestingly, the behavior seems triggered by two-dimensional formatting of the power on my system: if I write `(a+1)^2` instead of using the superscript form, the parenthesis matching seems unaffected by quotes. Is that true on on your system as well?

Comment: @MarcoB. Yes, that's true on mine. I've also run into situations where the matching between a `Slot` and the corresponding `&` will get lost, but I wasn't able to reproduce that; I can't quite remember when that happens.

Comment: I remember another question about a similar problem, but not well enough to find it.  Can anyone else do better?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. [This one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58416/after-editing-a-file-mathematica-10-interprets-2-as-2), I think. It's essentially the same problem. Mark as duplicate? That one is still unanswered.

Comment: @march Yes!  Thank you.  Also somewhat related:  [(35202)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35202/121),
[(76410)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76410/121)

Comment: I have this same problem on OSX 10.10.5, with Mathematica 10.0.1.0.

Comment: What is the status of this bug on OS X in *Mathematica* 10.3.1?

Comment: I don't see this in V11.0.0 under Linux.

Comment: @mikado. It's possible that it was never a problem on Linux machines (I don't think I've seen any comments about that). Can you verify that it was?

Comment: @march I don't see it on V10.4 under Linux

Comment: @march This bug seems to be resolved in v11.  Can you confirm?

Comment: @QuantumDot. Unfortunately, I do not have access to v11. I'm still stuck at V10.0.1.

Comment: @QuantumDot.  In my (new) copy of V11.3, this seems to be resolved.